# jmeter: Sharable reports

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have the following problem:

JMeter creates multifile HTML reports where you get the report as a folder with multiple pages and CSS/js.

The report looks quite nice when you explore it on your local machine. However, it's hard to share folders.

In our current routines, we have to share reports via email or Slack, and it kind of implies archiving folders, which is not ideal (e.g. if it's hard to see the report, people will not open it).

Also, converting HTML to PDF with a standard print dialog does not work due to the multifile and JS-rich (collapsable components). So, usually, the file looks quite ugly and does not return the full page.

I wonder if there are solutions to the problem.

Is there a way to generate a PDF? Or any other smart options?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) to generate charts you want to "share" and CSV versions of the tables you want to "share" and then build a single HTML or PDF file with them
2. [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool which has [Existing Results Loader](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ResultsLoader/) executor allowing uploading your test report to [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) platform and you will be able to download a single-file rich report from there

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I go with option 1, as I see it, I will get a list of pngs and csvs. How do I use the resulting csvs in the report?

Comment: In general, I like JMeter reports. And I like the way I have it done automatically. Just the problem is to share them in a good way (I am not quite ready to store them on a third party cloud solution like BlazeMeter)